# How to map Map<String, MyValueObject> with xml in jpa?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

To decouple my domain model from persistance mechanism, I'm using XML to config mapping from my domain model to db entities.
I have this entity:

```
public class Tenant {
   long id;
   Map<String, AuthApp> authApps;
   ...
}
```

And this value object:

```
public class AuthApp {
   String authCode;
   int durationInDays;
   ...
}
```

The value object has no lifecycle itself, it's denpends on the entity.
I create two table in my RDBMS, "tenant" and "auth_app".
Can any one guide me how to write the JPA xml for this case?
The XML I've coded so far is like this:

```
<entity class="Tenant">
  <table name="tenant"/>
  <attributes>
    <id name="id"><generated-value strategy="AUTO" /></id>
    <element-collection name="authApp">
      <map-key name="app_id"/>
      <collection-table name="auth_app">
        <join-column name="tenant_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
      </collection-table>
    </element-collection>
  </attributes>
</entity>
```

I don't know if it's right or not, and how to continue.

BTW, I'm using hibernate as the JPA provider.

Comment: "AuthApp" is presumably an entity then? or are you using an attribute converter to persist it?

Comment: @DN1 No, it's not an entity but a value object, as I mentioned above. And I'm not using converter, I wonder it can work in this case.

Comment: If it is not JPA aware (entity, embeddable) then you cannot persist it unless you provide an `@AttributeConverter` to convert the multiple fields (of AuthApp) into a single column value for the table storing the map.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! Thanks to DN1's comment, I've been aware of that the "value object" is the "embeddable" in JPA semantic. So, defining "AuthApp" as "embeddable", using "map-key-column" instead of "map-key", Done.
The whole thing is like this:

```
<entity class="Tenant">
  <table name="tenant"/>
  <attributes>
    <id name="id"><generated-value strategy="AUTO" /></id>
    <element-collection name="authApp" target-class="AuthApp">
      <map-key-column name="app_id"/>
      <collection-table name="auth_app">
        <join-column name="tenant_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
      </collection-table>
    </element-collection>
  </attributes>
</entity>
<embeddable class="AuthApp">
   <attributes>
       ......
   </attributes>
</embeddable>
......
```